# How can I prevent image scaling with SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I've been playing with SpriteKit but noticed some slightly odd behaviour in the way it loads in images, I'm trying to write code that cuts up a spritesheet and displays single frames using `[SKTexture textureWithRect]` but the images always come out too small.

From doing some more testing I've found just writing this code:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        SKSpriteNode *imageNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"tree2-final.png"];
        imageNode.position = CGPointMake(400, 400);
        [self addChild:imageNode];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In a subclass of SKScene loads a window with my image but it's too small, below is a screenshot of the problem. It shows the window running my code that displays the image along with the image displaying fullsize in preview.

I'm guessing this has something to do with retina images, in which case is there a simple way to just turn it off and have it display images at their original size?

[image]

Comment: What is the size of your scene and what is the size of tree2-final.png? If you are using preview to view your image file, it does not necessarily display it at true size. It generally shows it larger than the actual size.

Comment: BTW, SpriteKit is a little wonky with image loading. But if you have a retina image, you will need a "@2x" in the file name for it to display properly on a retina display. If you do not have a "@2x" in it, it will actually scale the image up.

Comment: The image size is 256x256 and the scene size is 1024x768 (I'm building it as a Mac app rather than iOS).

Comment: Oh and I did try copying the image and adding @2x to it but it didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: What values do you get for imageNode.size as well as for imageNode.xScale and imageNode.yScale? FYI, I really only do iOS, so if it is a weird MacOS thing I may not be able to help.

Comment: And one other thing you should try and do is create a 256x256 solid color texture (like red). Then display that. Take a screen capture and you should be able to find out ratio wise what scale difference there is between the scene size and the sprite.

Comment: xscale and yscale both return 1, but imageNode.size returns 61x61 which is really weird. I've also found if I re-export the image as a gif then it does detect it's 256x256, jpg and png both report as 61x61 though.

Answer (score 1):

When creating an `SKSpriteNode` using the `spriteWithImageNamed` method in iOS, an image's dots per inch (DPI) is ignored. For a Mac OS X game, an image's DPI affects the size of the sprite. If the DPI of your image is greater than 72, the size of your sprite will be proportionally smaller. For example, if your DPI is 144, your sprite will be 1/2 of width and height of the size of the image.